# Xaml CloseButtonText giving InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a basic UAP application for running on a Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise device. However, when I try to open even the most basic of ContentDialogs I get an InvalidCastException when trying to set its CloseButtonText

```
 using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
 ...

 private async void DisplayNoWifiDialog()
    {
        ContentDialog noWifiDialog = new ContentDialog {
            Title = "No wifi connection",
            Content = "Check your connection and try again.",
            CloseButtonText = "Ok"
        };

        ContentDialogResult result = await noWifiDialog.ShowAsync();
    }
```

> Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog'
>   to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.IContentDialog2'.
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.    at
>   System.StubHelpers.StubHelpers.GetCOMIPFromRCW_WinRT(Object objSrc,
>   IntPtr pCPCMD, IntPtr& ppTarget)    at
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog.put_CloseButtonText(String
>   value)    at
>   MyApplication.MainPage.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.b__6_0(Object
>   state)    at
>   System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()

The minimum and target Win 10 platforms are set to 10240 and 15063 respectively. CloseButtonText was introduced in 1703.

Comment: I set the minimum and target Win 10 platforms are set to 10240 and 15063 respectively that it has no exception. By the way, my  Windows 10 Mobile OS build is 10.15063.297. If you deploy it on the Windows 10 Mobile, you should be able to check the OS build of your phone.

Comment: I was testing on a device that was running Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise 10.0.10586.218

Comment: The `CloseButtonText` is added in Windows 10 Creators Update (introduced v10.0.15063.0) that we can not use it in Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise 10.0.10586.218. It will throw the InvalidCastException.

Comment: I'm having a very similar issue in my Xamarin.Forms UWP custom renderer for a Label, where it says the Control (type `TextBlock`) cannot be cast to `ITextBlock5`. Posted question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47697540/xamarin-forms-uwp-invalidcastexception-when-trying-to-set-textdecorations-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var dialog = new ContentDialog() {
        Title = "No wifi connection",
        //RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark,
        //FullSizeDesired = true,
        MaxWidth = this.ActualWidth // Required for Mobile!
    };
panel.Children.Add(new TextBlock {
    Text = "Check your connection and try again." ,
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap,
});

// a check box for example
var cb = new CheckBox {
    Content = "Don't show this dialog again"
};

panel.Children.Add(cb);
dialog.Content = panel;

// Add Buttons
dialog.PrimaryButtonText = "OK";
dialog.PrimaryButtonClick += delegate {
   // do something
};
// Show Dialog
var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Or using `MessageDialog`

```
 var dialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog(
                "Check your connection and try again." ,
                "No wifi connection");

    dialog.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Ok") { Id = 0 });
   // add another button if you want to
   //dialog.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Cancel") { Id = 1 });

    // example: check mobile and add another button
    if (Windows.System.Profile.AnalyticsInfo.VersionInfo.DeviceFamily != "Windows.Mobile") 
    {
        // Adding a 3rd command will crash the app when running on Mobile !!!
        //dialog.Commands.Add(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Maybe later") { Id = 2 });
    }

    dialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
    //dialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;

    var result = await dialog.ShowAsync();
```

Comment: I don't want to use a MessageDialog as that is to be deprecated; Also, just using the PrimaryButtonText sort of works (it cuts off the button so I can't see it) and I can use a SecondaryButtonText as well; but why does CloseButtonText throw an exception?

Comment: @monty Because the ContentDialog has no Property 'CloseButtonText' according to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentDialog

Comment: @TheTanic It's not an inherited property, but it is listed as a property in that api link you supplied. The code I used to test this was taken directly from that page.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `SecondaryButtonText` instead of `CloseButtonText`.

Or go to `Project Properties` and set **Min version** on Application tab to `Windows 10 Creators Update (10.0; Build 15063)`. But this will make the app unavailable to older versions of Windows 10.

P.S. I would appreciate if Microsoft start thinking about adding compile-time check for such cases instead of throwing completely unclear exception at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

**Worked On Windows 10**

I got to this SO question after successfully running the following code on a Win10 box:

```
private async void DisplayToggleDialog()
{
   ContentDialog toggleDialog = new ContentDialog
   {
      Title = "You've Toggled the Item",
              Content = "The Item is On",
              CloseButtonText = "Ok"
   };

   ContentDialogResult result = await toggleDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```

**Failed On Server 2016**

I then built and ran the code on a Server 2016, running Visual Studio 2017 v15.5.0 Preview 4.0 and when the ContentDialog gets instantiated I get the following error:

[image: cannot cast type to icontentdialog2]

I changed the code to use the PrimaryButtonText in place of the CloseButtonText (which seems to no longer be defined under UWP) and it worked.

```
private async void DisplayToggleDialog()
{
   ContentDialog toggleDialog = new ContentDialog
   {
      Title = "You've Toggled the Item",
              Content = "The Item is On",
              PrimaryButtonText = "Ok"
   };

   ContentDialogResult result = await toggleDialog.ShowAsync();
}
```