# Xamarin.Forms UWP - InvalidCastException when trying to set TextDecorations for TextBlock

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp, textblock, xamarin.uwp

In a Xamarin.Forms project, I'm trying to allow underlined Labels. So I have a custom renderer, and I'm trying to do something simple:

```
Control.TextDecorations = TextDecorations.Underline;
```

It compiles just fine, but when the app launches, I'm getting an InvalidCastException on that line which says:

> **System.InvalidCastException:** 'Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ITextBlock5'.'

Here's a screenshot of the exception:

[image]

Also, when inspecting the Control, I noticed there are a ton of InvalidCastException exceptions on other properties of the TextBlock control as well - here's a small sample:

[image]

Why is it trying to cast to a `ITextBlock5` type? Is this a UWP bug? Is there a workaround to get underline to work?

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, Version 1511, OS Build 10586.1045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBlock_TextDecorationsProperty), the TextDecorations property wasn't introduced until version 15063. You're probably getting that exception because you're on an earlier version of Windows.

As a workaround, you can create an `Underline()` object and add a `Run()` object to the Underline object's Inlines collection, like this:

```
// first clear control content
Control.Inlines.Clear();

// next create new Underline object and
// add a new Run to its Inline collection
var underlinedText = new Underline();
underlinedText.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = "text of xamarin element here" });

// finally add the new Underline object
// to the Control's Inline collection
Control.Inlines.Add(underlinedText);
```

Inside the custom renderer's `OnElementChanged()` override method, it would look something like this:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    var view = e.NewElement as LabelExt; // LabelExt => name of PCL custom Label class
    var elementExists = (view != null && Control != null);
    if (!elementExists)
    {
        return;
    }

    // add underline to label
    Control.Inlines.Clear();
    var underlinedText = new Underline();
    underlinedText.Inlines.Add(new Run { Text = view.Text });
    Control.Inlines.Add(underlinedText);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `TextDecorations` property is [documented on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBlock#PROPERTIES) to be supported on version 15063 and later.

You can use the `ApiInformation` class to check at runtime whether the property is avaiable or not.